# connect gigabit eth switch to 802.11ac network

Tags: bridge, gigabit-ethernet, 802.11ac

I have a wireless router (802.11ac) for internet access which I use directly to connect to with my WLAN devices. I also have small LAN on a gigabit switch. How do I connect the switch to the wireless network?

EDIT1: I want to keep the switch because I get 800 mbps between devices connected to it. I don't want to run a long ethernet cable between switch and router.

Comment: What do you mean by `I have a fast 802.11ac network connected to my residential gateway router.`?? Please draw a diagram for the WLAN and the wired network.

Comment: If you have a wireless router you should have LAN ports on the router as well. Is there a problem connecting directly to the router?

Comment: I don't want to run a long ethernet cable.

Comment: By "fast 802.11ac ..." I meant that I have no complaints about the performance of the wireless network.

Comment: You need to put this info in your question. Anyway I got you an answer, hope this helps. PS. don't ask for specific devices you can buy. Those questions are our of topic and will be closed.

Comment: I revised the answer a bit

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you couldn't just use one of the ports (uplink or auto-uplink) to wire it to one of the LAN-side connectors on the gateway router (parallel to the wireless router), or to one of the LAN-side connectors on the wireless router (most of them have at least a few in addition to the wifi radios).  That would be the easiest way.

Each single wired/ethernet device could be converted to wifi using an ethernet-to-wifi adapter (like an IOGear GWU637).  This would mean eliminating the gigabit switch so it could get expensive.  Not sure if you could use that kind of device to bridge/connect an entire switch (i.e. "adapt" an uplink port), but I guess you could also try that.

Some mesh wireless network devices have ethernet ports on every node so you might be able use a few nodes of something like a TP-link Deco-5, with one node ethernet connected to the wifi-router or gateway, and the other ethernet connected to the gigabit switch.  Presumably, that would carry the traffic from all devices on the switch over the mesh backhaul (but I haven't tried that one either).

The most ambitious, and most flexible option I know of is to load OpenWRT on a Raspberry Pi-4 model B, and configure the 802.11ac wifi adapter as the WAN network, and the Gigabit ethernet as the LAN network.  There's a bit of a learning curve to set that up but it might be your best bet for connecting the "dots" you described.

See:

- https://openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi_foundation/raspberry_pi
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/

Comment: I want the switch for the 800 mbps connection it gives me between my windows and linux boxes. I just need internet connectivity for  my LAN, without running a long cable. I heard about a business using a "wireless access point in client mode" but I don't know what the corresponding consumer thing is.

Comment: The "consumer thing" probably includes almost any wifi access point / router that has firmware features to allow the WAN and LAN to be reversed.  The ethernet jack that would normally be on the WAN side (e.g. connected to a cable modem) would instead connect to your gigabit switch.  The wifi radio that would normally be configured as "infrastructure" (meaning other devices can connect to it), would instead be configured as a client device (like a wifi adapter in a laptop or phone).  This might help explain: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless

Comment: The previously mentioned raspberry pi option with OpenWRT essentially makes the raspberry pi into a wifi + ethernet bridge/router.  OpenWRT just gives you more control over how each of the network hardware devices is configured.  If you find a suitable Wifi access point / router for which OpenWRT is available/supported, that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

**I would advise** to connect the switch directly to the router. For 1GB-WLAN You can run standard Cat6 patch cable (stranded, AWG24) up to 85m. At least in theory but that depends on the quality of your cable and the devices you are connecting to and on the EMI etc. With consumer devices I will try to keep the length as short as possible. This will give you a much better connection then going through WLAN would (faster an more reliable).

**However** if you need to connect the switch directly to the WLAN there you could bridge the WLAN to LAN and attach your switch there. Depending on what you already have and how much you want to spend there are a lot of options e.g. via an WLAN to LAN adapter (the only consumer grade one I tried out myself was the TP-Link TL-WR902AC for mobile use), via an WiFi extender that has an Ethernet port or simply through a Windows or Linux machine that brides the the WLAN and Ethernet network card, etc.)

**A third option** would be to use powerline networking to connect the router to the switch.